# Are there more frames in compressed BAG files?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the same process to measure how many frames I supposedly have lost during recording with an Intel RealSense D435 camera as outlined here: https://answers.ros.org/question/332910/frames-dropped-during-video-recording/

I am finding that I have many files where 10000-15000 per 20000-30000 frames are being dropped... This is very significant, so I wanted to confirm whether there are "hidden" frames in compressed BAG files.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334924/are-there-more-frames-in-compressed-bag-files?/) by [Abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/45546/abraham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no "hidden" messages (frames or otherwise) in compressed bag files.

As suggested in the previous post, I would attempt to inspect the bag file in rqt_bag, to see what the timing of the missing frames is. Based on missing almost exactly half of your expected data, I suspect your sensor may be running at 15fps instead of the expected 30 fps.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0